# Как отправить в FCM несколько сообщений за раз?

Tags: php, firebase, push-уведомления

Привет, подскажите как можно отправить в firebase cloud messaging несколько сообщений за раз. Сейчас я отправляю их по одному так:

```
$fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => is_array($this->notification->getFcmToken()) ?
            $this->notification->getFcmToken() :
            array($this->notification->getFcmToken()),
        'data' => array(
            "message" => $this->notification->getMessage(),
            "type_message" => $this->notification->getTypeNotification())
    );
    $this->notification->getMessage();
    $headers = array(
        "Authorization:key = " . self::API_GCM_KEY,
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::URL_GCM_SEND);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если $this->notification->getFcmToken() вернет массив токенов - отправится на несколько токенов, даже в коде есть.

---

Вопрос получен при помощи IT вопросника
https://pushall.ru/?fs=927

Comment: возможно я не корректно выразился, в коде приведенном выше отправляется одно сообщение на несколько устройств. Мне нужно одновременно отправить несколько сообщений с разным содержанием в FCM. Т.е. пачку сообщений

Comment: FCM это не умеет, для разных уведомлений - разные запросы